# tfs2015 buildcontroller is failing to copy one csproj file to repository directory

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I hope someone can help me with the following problem. I have recently upgraded my tfs 2013 to tfs 2015. I have detached my collections and attached them in tfs 2015. So far so good. I have successfully configured a build agent (VSO).

One solution runs fine with the build agent and produces successful builds.

My other solutions doesn't. 
This solution contains 31 projects. The problem i am facing is that my complete solution is being copied to the in the (_work) directory, all my projects are in separate folders and everything looks good, except for one file, this is a csproj file of one of my projects. This specific file is missing in the project directory and I don't know why.

I cannot find out why this file is not in the project directory where it is supposed to be.

Can someone please help me figuring out this problem?

Thanks,

RESOLVED (not really but..):
I have configured the xaml build controller and now i am able to build all of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this problem again, two ways for you reference:

- You could manually copying the file from one location to the required
  location.
- Deleting the files from  (_work) directory and close VS, rebuilding the project.

Moreover, since you have upgraded TFS to 2015, you could also try to use the new build system [vNext build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview) to get better outcomes.